# Python HMAC-SHA1 calculation goin wrong

Tags: python-2.7

I stuck in python while developing security access python script using HMAC-SHA1 algorithm key.

I have python version 2.7 which already includes HMAC-SHA1 libraries. Using library I tried to write script in the below mentioned way. But unfortunately when I execute the script the key calculated is different from the expected key given to me.

## ---------------Code Start--------------------------

```
from hashlib import sha1
import hmac
import base64
import hashlib, binascii
SecurityConst_key = "121a3ace5827a3b6" #(0x12 1A 3A CE 58 27 A3 B6)
msg = "4272696C6C69616E63655F6175746F21" # Brilliance_auto!
key = hmac.new(SecurityConst_key, msg, sha1).digest()
key = base64.b64encode(key)
print binascii.hexlify(key)
```

## ----------------Code End----------------------

Key calculated is : `4d416963747a41737a546f774530464373536e4d646b6c323972673d`

Which is different from the leftmost 128 bits.

Expected key is: `0x15 4A ED 59 CF B3 2E DC 37 8D 30 6B 0F 02 AB 6B`
(Truncate the 160 bits result. Output the leftmost 128 bits of the HMAC, it is the Key)

Can some one please help me to fix the possible issue.

Answer (score 0):

So,what you need to be really careful of is understanding whether something is a byte-string or a hex-string. In python, most crypto and mac and sha's take binary strings. So your line:

```
SecurityConst_key = "121a3ace5827a3b6" #(0x12 1A 3A CE 58 27 A3 B6)
```

is not true. Thats actually `0x31 32 31 ...` You need to get your data right first. Try hex decoding your key and your data before passing it in. "121a3ace5827a3b6".decode("hex").

On the other hand, for the data, you could just use the raw string.

Secondly you are also base64 encoding your output of the mac before printing that off as hex. That seems - wrong. You either base64 it and look at that, or you hex-encode it, and look at that. Base64 by design is ascii-printable (for hashes you traditionally print in hex)